# Where was this photograph taken? LG TV Screensaver

Tags: where-on-earth

Where was this photograph taken? The picture is part of LG TV's generic screensaver slideshow.

[image: LG screensaver photo]

Comment: I think it looks a lot like Cracker Lake in Glacier National Park in the US. But the lake is smaller than I remember, so I could be wrong. Also I think Cracker Lake has only one lake, not two.

Answer (score 2):

The image appears to be a stock image from: https://www.istockphoto.com/gb/photo/mount-paterno-and-piani-lake-in-the-dolomites-gm520888995-50617662

Which describes the location as "Mount Paterno and Piani Lake in the Dolomites"

Link to map: https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/46.6380/12.3149

Comment: If the location is a real photo at all. Something is off with the water, that usually used to be very difficult to replicate and still is, to a degree, when generating CGI imagery.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's a photo. It's much easier to take an actual photograph than to CGI something like this. And the water looks fine to me (in the original, at least; the version in this question is a photo of a TV screen with lots of reflections).